# ClassCastException causes my program to crash

Tags: android, singleton

I have two Activities along with one Application class, and whenever I call my Application class in one of the Activities the program crashes. Here are the onCreate() methods for the two Activities:

MainMenu:

```
protected BluetoothApplication myBt;

private TextView bluetoothText;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE );
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myBt = ((BluetoothApplication)getApplicationContext());

    bluetoothText = new TextView(this);

    customTitleBar( getText( R.string.app_name).toString(), bluetoothText.getText().toString() );
}
```

DeviceList:

```
protected BluetoothApplication myBt;

protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    // Setup the window
    //requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS );
    setContentView( R.layout.device_list );

    myBt = (BluetoothApplication)getApplicationContext();

    // Set result CANCELED in case the use backs out
    //setResult( Activity.RESULT_CANCELED );

    // Initialize the button to perform device discovery
    Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_scan );
    scanButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick( View v ) {
            doDiscovery();
            v.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }
    });

    // Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and one
    // for newly discovered devices
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, R.layout.device_name );
    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, R.layout.device_name );

    // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
    ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.paired_devices );
    pairedListView.setAdapter( mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter );
    pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener( mDeviceClickListener );

    // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
    ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.new_devices );
    newDevicesListView.setAdapter( mNewDevicesArrayAdapter );

    // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND );
    this.registerReceiver( mReceiver, filter );

    // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
    filter = new IntentFilter( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED );
    this.registerReceiver( mReceiver, filter );

    // Get a set of currently paired devices
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBt.getMyBtAdapter().getBondedDevices();

    if( pairedDevices.size() > 0 ) {
        findViewById( R.id.title_paired_devices ).setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        for ( BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices ) {
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add( device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() );
        }
    } else {
        String noDevices = getResources().getText( R.string.none_paired ).toString();
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add( noDevices );
    }

}
```

Both of these Activities load fine when I remove the lines involving the BluetoothApplication. I have tried changing getApplicationContext() to getApplication().

BluetoothApplication:

```
public class BluetoothApplication extends Application {
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothApplication";
private static final boolean D = true;

// Member fields
private BluetoothAdapter myAdapter;
private Handler myHandler;
private BluetoothDevice myBtDevice;
private BluetoothSocket mySocket;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;
private ConnectThread myConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread myConnectedThread;
private int myState;


// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;


//In SDK15 (4.0.3) this method is now public as
//Bluetooth.fetchUuisWithSdp() and BluetoothDevice.getUuids()
public ParcelUuid[] servicesFromDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Class[] par = {};
        Method method = cl.getMethod("getUuids", par);
        Object[] args = {};
        ParcelUuid[] retval = (ParcelUuid[]) method.invoke(device, args);
        return retval;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}



public void onCreate( ) {
    myAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    myAdapter.enable();

}


public BluetoothAdapter getMyBtAdapter() {
    return myAdapter;
}

/**
 * Set the connection state of the device. 
 * @param state
 */
public synchronized void setState( int state ) {
    if( D ) Log.d(TAG, " setState() " + myState + " -> " + state );
    myState = state;

    myHandler.obtainMessage( MainMenu.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1 ).sendToTarget();
}

/**
 * Get the connection state.
 */
public synchronized int getState() {
    return myState;
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionFailed() {
    setState( STATE_NONE );

    // Send failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = myHandler.obtainMessage( MainMenu.MESSAGE_TOAST );
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString( " ", "unable to connect to device" );
    msg.setData( bundle );
    myHandler.sendMessage( msg );
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionLost() {
    setState( STATE_NONE );

    Message msg = myHandler.obtainMessage( MainMenu.MESSAGE_TOAST );
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString( "ASdasd", "Device connection was lost" );
    msg.setData( bundle );
    myHandler.sendMessage( msg );
}

public synchronized void start() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG,  "start" );

    if( myConnectThread != null ) {
        myConnectThread.cancel();
        myConnectThread = null;
    }

    if( myConnectedThread != null ) {
        myConnectedThread.cancel();
        myConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState( STATE_NONE );
}

public synchronized void connect( BluetoothDevice device ) {
    if( D ) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device );

    if( myState == STATE_CONNECTING ) {
        if( myConnectThread != null ) { myConnectThread.cancel(); myConnectThread = null;}
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if( myConnectedThread != null ) {myConnectedThread.cancel(); myConnectedThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    myConnectThread = new ConnectThread( device );
    myConnectThread.start();
    setState( STATE_CONNECTING );
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managin a Bluetooth connection
 */
public synchronized void connected( BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device ) {
    if( D ) Log.d(TAG, "connected" );

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if( myConnectThread != null ) {
        myConnectThread.cancel();
        myConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if( myConnectedThread != null ) {
        myConnectedThread.cancel();
        myConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    myConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread( socket );
    myConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = myHandler.obtainMessage( MainMenu.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME );
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString( MainMenu.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName() );
    msg.setData( bundle );
    myHandler.sendMessage( msg );

    setState( STATE_CONNECTED );
}

/**
 * Stop ALL threads
 */

public synchronized void stop() {
    if(D) Log.d( TAG, "stop" );

    if( myConnectThread != null ) {
        myConnectThread.cancel();
        myConnectThread = null;
    }

    if( myConnectedThread != null ) {
        myConnectedThread.cancel();
        myConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState( STATE_NONE );
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 */
public void write( byte[] out ) {
    ConnectedThread r;
    synchronized( this ) {
        if( myState != STATE_CONNECTED ) return;
        r = myConnectedThread;
    }
    r.write( out );
}

public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread( BluetoothDevice device ) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        ParcelUuid[] uuids = servicesFromDevice( myBtDevice );

        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( uuids[0].getUuid() );
        } catch (IOException e ) {
            Log.e( TAG, "create() failed", e );
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i( TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread" );
        setName( "ConnectThread" );

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        myAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            connectionFailed();
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch ( IOException e2 ) {
                Log.e( TAG, "Unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2 );
            }
            BluetoothApplication.this.start();
            return;
        }

        synchronized ( BluetoothApplication.this ) {
            myConnectThread = null;
        }

        connected( mmSocket, mmDevice );
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try { 
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e ) {
            Log.e( TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e );
        }
    }
}


/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread( BluetoothSocket socket ) {
        Log.d( TAG, "create ConnectedThread" );
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            Log.e(TAG,  "temp sockets not created", e );
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread" );
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        while( true ){
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read( buffer );
                myHandler.obtainMessage( MainMenu.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer ).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e ) {
                Log.e( TAG, "disconnected", e );
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to connected OutStream.
     * 
     */
    public void write( byte[] buffer ) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write( buffer );
            myHandler.obtainMessage( MainMenu.MESSAGE_WRITE, buffer.length, -1, buffer ).sendToTarget();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
                Log.e( TAG, "Exception during write", e );
        }   
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e ) {
            Log.e( TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e );
        }

    }
}
}
```

I also think there may be something wrong with how I entered the Application class into my Manifest file:

MODIFIED MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.eti.commander"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name = ".BluetoothApplication" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DeviceList"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:label="@string/devices">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

this is the LogCat:

```
06-18 09:09:26.625: I/Process(2097): Sending signal. PID: 2097 SIG: 9
06-18 09:17:32.241: D/AndroidRuntime(2304): Shutting down VM
06-18 09:17:32.241: W/dalvikvm(2304): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.eti.commander/my.eti.commander.MainMenu}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at my.eti.commander.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:47)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-18 09:17:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2304):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: it would be easier to find error if you post your stacktrace instead

Comment: Post your modified manifest file.

Comment: Now, your code looks fine, just only one assumption, put complete application name with package in application tag in manifest fiel like, my.eti.commander.BluetoothApplication and try it.

Comment: Doing that makes all of my references to my XML files come up as errors. I'm assuming its because it changes the path that the program looks for these files.

Comment: I'm sorry. Hahaha, turns out I forgot to add BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions to my manifest file, sheesh. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to give application name in your manifest file. Also there are two application tag in your manifest file, (remove second one)

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name=".BluetoothApplication"
>
```

and remove the last application node,

```
<application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:name="BluetoothApplication">
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be, that your activities are declared in an different application, than your BluetoothApplication. The way it is now, the application of the activities does not declare an implicit class, so the default Application class is used. You then try to cast that to BluetoothApplication in your activites, which it simply not is.

Try to get rid of the second application tag in your manifest and add android:name="BluetoothApplication" to the first application tag.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, fixed it but it still crashes

Comment: Just added it to my original post, and updated my manifest file

Answer (score 1):

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

You should add here

```
android:name=".BluetoothApplication"
```

to make OS know that you have your own class for application.
Also, remove this block:

```
<application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:name="BluetoothApplication">
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed that but it still crashes